# Google Maps not loading on 2nd panel/page

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am struggling to load Google maps on anything other than the first page.

In the example I have Google maps on page two; but when I move the code to page one, it is working.

Why is this not loading correctly on page two?

code which i move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Spytter/4mtyu/1202/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**.

Comment: This is a common issue asked many times (hidden map displayed in a tab).  What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I have moved it from the second page to the first page, then it is working. what is the resolution to make it working on the second page?

Comment: call `google.maps.trigger(map, 'resize')` once the second page is completely rendered.

Comment: Where in the fiddle must i put google.maps.trigger(map, 'resize')

Comment: After the new page/panel is completely rendered.

Comment: Got it working..as you suggested. :)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

i have created a new fiddle to show the page not loading, then when button clicked re-size the map.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/Spytter/4mtyu/1302/